# Error: request for member 'insert' which is of non-class type int* ?? What's wrong?

Tags: c++, stack, ifstream, dynamic-arrays

This is the error I'm getting:

> StatisticsProcessor.cpp: In member function ‘void StatisticsProcessor::loadData(std::string)’:
>   StatisticsProcessor.cpp:70:16: error: request for member ‘insert’ in ‘((StatisticsProcessor*)this)->StatisticsProcessor::dataArray’, which is of non-class type ‘Element* {aka int*}’
>   make: *** [StatisticsProcessor.o] Error 1

Here is that part of my code:

```
if(inStream.is_open()){
    for(int i = 0;;){
        if(!inStream.eof()){
            Element line = 0;
                if(i > 0){
                    inStream >> line;
                    dataArray.insert(line);
                }
                else{
                    dataArray = new(nothrow) Element[line];
                    assert(dataArray != 0);
                }
        }
        else if(inStream.eof()) break;
    }
            // Close file stream
            inStream.close();
}
```

and here is my insert function:

```
void StatisticsProcessor::insert(Element e){

    // Increment size
    size++;

    // Add in new value
    dataArray[size-1] = e;
}
```

Element is just a typedef for int, and dataArray is of type Element* 
inStream is an ifstream object, I'm trying to read numbers from a file and insert them
into my list class(essentially an array of integers).  What am i doing wrong??

Comment: Show us the declaration of `dataArray` inside the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've shown us, the `insert` is a member function of the `StatisticsProcessor` class.  If you want to call that function, the syntax would be:

```
x.insert(y);
```

Where `x` is an object of type `StatisticsProcessor` and `y` is an object of type `Element` (int).  Instead, your `x` is an `int*` (pointer to int).  Pointers don't have a member function named `insert`, nor any member functions at all, for that matter.

Comment: What would you suggest i do?

Comment: @Riptyde4: I would suggest you read a [C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), because to make this mistake is to have a fundamental gap in knowledge on the language.  A gap which I cannot possibly fill in this answer.

Comment: @Riptyde4 Change your array into a `std::vector` and use `push_back`.

Comment: I'm reading one lol, this is an assignment for a class i'm trying to wrap my head around. I can't use vectors my professor wants us to write our own list class

Comment: @Riptyde4 In that case, change `dataArray`'s type to use your list class instead. Assuming your list interface defines an `insert` method somewhere.

Comment: Hah! silly me I'm in the StatisticsProcessor class already I just changed it to plain insert(Element e) ... I have no idea why i was trying to call insert on dataArray .. I was very confused for a moment. Sorry for wasting all of your time!